# No clue where to put \thechapter

Tags: table-of-contents

In my ToC I need a chapter word next to chapters.

Where to put `\thechapter` to get result

```
\renewcommand*\@seccntformat[1]{ \csname the#1\endcsname.\enspace}
\def\numberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1.\hfil}}
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
\ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
 \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
 \setlength\@tempdima{1.0em}%
 \begingroup
   \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
   \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
   \leavevmode \bfseries
   \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
   \hskip -\leftskip
   #1\nobreak\mdseries
   \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
     \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
    mu$}\hfill
   \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
   \penalty\@highpenalty
 \endgroup
\fi}
%
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
%\vspace*{50\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
 \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
     \normalsize \bfseries \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}\space \thechapter
     \par\nobreak
     \vskip\baselineskip 
 \fi 
 \interlinepenalty\@M
 \LARGE \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
 \vskip 40\p@
}}
 %
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
 %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
   \normalfont
   \interlinepenalty\@M
   \LARGE \bfseries   #1\par\nobreak
   \vskip 40\p@
  }}
  %
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You are making your own document class? While such code snippets might seem good, this definitely needs a [full Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that would show us the complete context.

Comment: It is document class made by my teacher. I do not know where to put \thechapter to get word Chapter in ToC. It is not posible to give Minimal Working Example. It is a class file (.cls)

Comment: I don't understand why you don't mention that you want to have the word "Chapter" in your question. Read your question and try to understand it, having no more information than what is written there. You probably need to add `\chaptername{} ` (notice the space at the end) before `#1` in the definition of `\l@chapter`. But I'm afraid that the result will not be satisfactory. However, we cannot test it, so I don't think we can help you more.

Comment: Somewhat similar to @tohecz' suggestion, use `\@chapapp~#1\nobreak\mdseries` in your definition of `\l@chapter`.

Comment: Can you upload elsewhere (pastebin, for example) the `.cls` file so we can look at the definition for `\l@chapter`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: The definition of `\l@chapter` is included in the post.

Comment: @Werner Oh, I overlooked it. Anyway, I would still like to see the complete `.cls` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, you can add `\@chapapp` right before `#1` in the definition of `\l@chapter`; in the following example I used the book document class, but this will work with the other class used:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
\ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
 \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
 \setlength\@tempdima{1.0em}%
 \begingroup
   \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
   \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
   \leavevmode \bfseries
   \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
   \hskip -\leftskip
   \@chapapp~#1\nobreak\mdseries% NEW
   \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
     \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
    mu$}\hfill
   \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
   \penalty\@highpenalty
 \endgroup
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]